# How to remove trailing slash after file extension using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a [Ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) site at `example.com` and `www.example.com` (internally, it's running on port 2368). At the same time, I have a file named `form.pdf` and I want to make it available (view in browser, not to ask user to download) at:

- `example.com/form.pdf`
- `www.example.com/form.pdf`

With configuration below, it only works if it contains trailing slash after the `.pdf` extension like so:

- `example.com/form.pdf/`
- `www.example.com/form.pdf/`

PDF file path:

`/var/www/ghost/pdfs/form.pdf`

Config file path:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost`

Config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name 123.45.678.901 localhost example.com *.example.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location "/form.pdf" {
        alias /var/www/ghost/pdfs;
        index form.pdf;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

When I remove the trailing slash after the `.pdf` extension, I got 404 error.

Question:

How to correctly configure Nginx to make it work without the trailing slash at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file located at `/var/www/ghost/pdfs/form.pdf` that you would like to access using the URI `/form.pdf`. The obvious answer is to set the `root` to `/var/www/ghost/pdfs`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Your current attempt with the `alias` directive is relying on the `index` directive to return the file. The actual URI being returned is `/form.pdf/form.pdf`, but Nginx appends the value of the `index` directive when a URI ends with `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

So the correct solution to return a single URI at a specific location is:

```
location = /form.pdf { root /var/www/ghost/pdfs; }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.